# How can I convert this object of a custom class in byte[]?

Tags: java

I'm using the [SCAPI Library](http://scapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I have two `byte[]` values which I'm sending to the Receiver using Scapi's safe channel.

**Sender**:

```
byte[] x0 = keysArray[0][0].getBytes();
byte[] x1 = keysArray[0][1].getBytes();

OTOnByteArraySInput input = new OTOnByteArraySInput(x0, x1);

Channel channel = obliviousTransferChannelCreation();
sender.transfer(channel, input);
```

The Receiver gets one of the two values according to his sigma.

**Receiver**:

```
byte sigma = 0;
OTRBasicInput input = new OTRBasicInput(sigma);
Channel channel = obliviousTransferChannelCreation();
OTROutput output = null;

output = receiver.transfer(channel, input);
```

At this point I want to convert `output` to `byte[]` again (and then to String). But `output` is an object of `OTROutput`. I cannot find a method in the [SCAPI Api](http://cryptobiu.github.io/scapi/) to convert `OTROutput` to `byte[]` (or anything for that matter). Is there an option to convert custom classes to byte[]?

Comment: What are you needing to do with it once you convert it to a String?

Comment: Do not use `String` to store binary data! Especially since its `.getBytes()` method is dependent on the JVM's default encoding

Comment: @JoshChappelle Just read it. `keysArray[0][0]` is a String (it could be a message i.e. "Hello"). In order to send it through the Channel class I have to convert it to byte[]. When it reaches the receiver I want to read the message again.